# rails 4 JSON::ParserError (757: unexpected token at 'null'):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having the following method in my controller

```
@content = Post.where(sub_category_id: id).select('content')
unless @content.nil?
      @content.each do |content|
        form_array = JSON.parse(content.content)
        array_test << form_array.values
      end
```

My content column has the value as `null` so I am getting error as

```
JSON::ParserError (757: unexpected token at 'null'):
```

But why the unless loop is not working. The loop gets executed when the column has `null` value how to prevent it

**Edit-1**

Consider I have two rows in my database table

one is `{"Style":"coupe","Year":"2012","Color":"green"}` #This works fine

second is `null` #But this fails

Comment: Considering `unless @content.nil?` will return true on @content entries like "", '' and [], it would be wise to check either presence with `if @content.present?` or possibility of enumeration with `if @content.any?`

Answer (score 2):

your @content is an array, and can contain more than 1 element so, this means itcan contain element with single element also with value as `null`, but the array has an element inside it, so in your case your condition will fail, it should be:

```
@content.each do |content|

unless content.nil?

        form_array = JSON.parse(content.content) if content.content.present?
        array_test << form_array.values
end

end
```

Comment: I guess your json statement formed is not correct..can you put on your json content here..??

Comment: just a wild guess that your `"` may have been escaped to like this `\"`, if it is so to resolve this see the update in my  answer..

Comment: i almost understood whatz your problem, could you show me the json string when its `null`??